# Inlining a method to increase performance but it executes slower in C#

Tags: c#, if-statement, optimization, inline

I am trying to remove a method to optimize my code. It seems I didn't gain any performance, moreover, the "optimized" code is slower! Is it faster to call a method than to create a variable in the loop? Why?

Why the following code is faster (1.3-1.5 seconds)

```
public void getPureText(string notClearedText)
{
    string peeledText = "";


    foreach (var symbol in notClearedText)
    {
        if(isCyrillic(symbol))
            peeledText += Char.ToLower(symbol);
        else
            peeledText += " ";
    }
}

private bool isCyrillic(int letterCode)
{
    switch (letterCode)
    {
        case 1028: // Є
        case 1108: // є
        case 1030: // І
        case 1110: // і
        case 1031: // Ї
        case 1111: // ї
        case 1168: // Ґ
        case 1169: // ґ
        case 32:  // " "
        case 39:  // '
                  //case 45:  // -
            return true;
        default:
            return
                1040 <= letterCode && letterCode <= 1103 &&  // Cyrillic
                letterCode != 1066 &&  // Ъ
                letterCode != 1067 &&  // Ы
                letterCode != 1098  // ъ
                ||
                65 <= letterCode && letterCode <= 90
                ||
                97 <= letterCode && letterCode <= 122
                ;
    }

}
```

than the "optimized" version (1.5-1.8 seconds)? What am I missing?

```
public void getPureText(string notClearedText)
{
    string peeledText = "";

    foreach (var symbol in notClearedText)
    {
      int letterCode = symbol;

      switch (letterCode)
      {
        case 1028: // Є
        case 1108: // є
        case 1030: // І
        case 1110: // і
        case 1031: // Ї
        case 1111: // ї
        case 1168: // Ґ
        case 1169: // ґ
        case 32:  // " "
        case 39:  // ' //case 45:  // -
            peeledText += Char.ToLower(symbol);
            break;
        default:
            if (
                1040 <= letterCode && letterCode <= 1103 && // Cyrillic
                letterCode != 1066 && // Ъ
                letterCode != 1067 && // Ы
                letterCode != 1098 // ъ
                ||
                65 <= letterCode && letterCode <= 90
                ||
                97 <= letterCode && letterCode <= 122
            )
                peeledText += Char.ToLower(symbol);
            else
                peeledText += " ";
            
            break;
         }
    }
}
```

I have run dozens of tests using

```
void TestPerformance()
{
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

    sw.Start();
    _textRepository.getPureText(RawTextExamples.veryLongText);
    sw.Stop();

    unitTestFormGuess.show(sw.Elapsed.ToString());
}
```

P.S.
As you see I removed some code from getPureText(), made it return void, then measured time again: the same result. Something wrong is there...

P.P.S.
Configuration: Debug.

**EDIT**

For `peeledText` replaced type  `string` to `StringBuilder`.

Configuration: release.

Size of the string is the same: 150 KB.

3 series of the testing for 500 iterations each.

- With method `isCyrillic` code: 6.63-6.70 milliseconds
- Inlined: 6.80-6.90 milliseconds (still slower o_0)
- Inlined but using RegEx: 6.62-6.70 milliseconds
- With method `isCyrillic` but using `HashSet` instead of the `switch`: 7.89-8.32 milliseconds.

Comment: Don't perform benchmarking in Debug, always use Release. Don't do it with a debugger attached and don't do it yourself (use something like Benchmarks.Net). If you do it yourself, Always execute the method many times before you start timing it in order to properly JIT the method

Comment: Method calls have virtually no overhead. Moving code between methods isn't going to alter the performance one bit. One potential performance gain here is to use `StringBuilder` instead of all of those `+=` calls. But that may not be any faster either as the overhead of creating the class may outweigh the allocations on the stack

Comment: You should benchmark things with release, not debug, builds. When repeating the test, how much does the time vary? Also, does a `StringBuilder` have an effect? I haven’t kept up with .NET in a long time but the `+=` in a loop would have been very slow (quadratic) once (and if it’s now optimized, there might a complexity limit after which it can’t be – although that probably isn’t the difference here). Also in general both compilers are capable of making optimizations like inlining themselves.

Comment: I'd also build the string then call `ToLower` on the whole string not each individual char, but again you'd have to test this to see if it made any difference

Comment: `RegEx` is also another option...

Comment: If the code is taking 1.6 seconds to run, then the input string is rather large. I'd stop using string concatenation and start using a string builder, its probably faster and much more memory efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code is taking 1.6 seconds to run processing one single input string, then its a rather large one. I'd [stop using string concatenation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/306822/how-to-improve-string-concatenation-performance-in-visual-c) (`+=`) and start using a [`System.Text.StringBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=netcore-3.1), its probably faster and much more memory efficient:

```
public void getPureText(string notClearedText)
{
    var peeledText = new StringBuilder(notClearedText.Length);

    foreach (var symbol in notClearedText)
    {
        if(isCyrillic(symbol))
            peeledText.Append(Char.ToLower(symbol));
        else
            peeledText.Append(' ');
    }
}
```

If your are calling `getPureText` in a somewhat tight loop you might consider reusing `buffer` simply clearing it and avoiding the newing cost on each call.

Benchmark it again in ***release mode, discarding the warm up run and without debugger attached***. If that still doesn't meet your performance goals then start micro optimizing inlining calls, etc. The jitter is pretty smart optimizing code so its probably not going to gain you much.

```
long Benchmark(string veryLongText, int repetitions)
{
    getPureText(veryLongText); //warmup
    var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    for (var i = 0; i < repetitions; i++)
        getPureText(veryLongText);

    watch.Stop();
    return watch.ElapsedMilliseconds/repetitions;
}
```